# External disk not readable in different enclosure

Tags: hard-drive, external-disk

I have two external disks with the same size and type of hard disk inside.
The LaCie hard disk is used for Time Machine backups. When I put the LaCie Time Machine disk into the Seagate enclosure, it says the "disk is not readable". Put back in the original place, everything is okay.

My goal is to switch the disks and keep the backups. What could be the problem and how can I access the Time Machine backups while using a different enclosure?

EDIT: experimenting with the Seagate hdd:
Formatted in Lacie then `diskutil info` gives 4096 bytes. Change enclosure to Seagate then `diskutil info` gives 512 bytes.

[image: Lacie enclosure with APFS Seagate disk.]

Comment: There's a fair chance one of the enclosures is 'faking' the block size as presented to the OS. I'm not sure if this is fixable in software, or whether a reformat would be the only way.

Comment: @Tetsujin Thanks for the info I'm searching this direction and found that `diskutil info` for Lacie is `Disk Size:                 3.0 TB (3000278364160 Bytes) (exactly 5859918680 512-Byte-Units)
   Device Block Size:         4096 Bytes`
and for Seagate: `Disk Size:                 3.0 TB (3000383225856 Bytes) (exactly 5860123488 512-Byte-Units)
   Device Block Size:         4096 Bytes`

Comment: @Tetsujin I formatted the Seagate hdd in the Lacie enclosure. Now when I plug in the Seagate enclosure with it's own hdd (which formatted in Lacie) the following displayed: `Disk Size:                 3.0 TB (3000592981504 Bytes) (exactly 5860533167 512-Byte-Units)
   Device Block Size:         512 Bytes`

Comment: That seems to confirm my suspicions, but it's a bit above my paygrade, sorry. I don't think it's 'fixable', each drive will have to stay in the enclosure it was formatted in.